# Get random products that are in stock

Tags: magento-1.9, filter, product-collection, stock-status

This is my code, i get random products here ...

```
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$products->addAttributeToSelect(array('name', 'thumbnail', 'price')); //feel free to add any other attribues you need.

Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->addVisibleFilterToCollection($products);
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInCatalogFilterToCollection($products);
Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($products);

$products->getSelect()->order('RAND()');
$products->getSelect()->limit(6);
```

... but this code show out of stock products too. I need just show in stock (available) products here. How can i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```
Mage::getSingleton('cataloginventory/stock')
    ->addInStockFilterToCollection($products);
```